# Using Openpxl in Python, create a new spreadsheet containing rows that have a specific substring

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel spreadsheet. I want the rows of spreadsheet that contains the substring "sigma" to be put into a new spreadsheet. I am using Openpxl in Python. I am stuck because something is wrong with my code. Please help.

```
import openpyxl

file = "C:\\Users\\1847\\Desktop\\DTO_aligned_to_EC_9_7_21_version.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=True)
ws = wb.active
w_new = openpyxl.Workbook()
w_new.save(C:\\Users\\1847\\Desktop\\DTO_aligned_to_EC_sigma.xlsx)

for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value is not None and "sigma" in cell.value:
            wb_new.save.append()
```

Once I find the cells, I want to append the row that contains these cells into a new worksheet which I am calling "w_save"

Comment: `wb_new.save.append()` makes no sense. Please explain in greater detail what you want to do with the cells when you find them.

Comment: Once I find the cells, I want to append the row that contains these cells into a new worksheet which I am calling "w_save"

Comment: Your code has `w_new` as the workbook name but no worksheet in it and you can only append sequences to worksheets.